# JCS remote cache

Tags: caching, jcs

I am having a use case to implement a system which receives updates every 30 minutes. 
We are doing a POC for implementing this using JCS remote cache.

The requirements are cache servers to be load balanced and consistent.

We are planning to have two servers with JCS cache and need to make the data in both consistent with the updates.

Is there any way we can implement.If anybody could provide some tips as how to configure this and advise with the configurations it would be really helpful